# Animate text like "carrousel" from start to end

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a practice app like a audio player, and want to add the animation of a specific text, when it's too long, to move from start to end like vanishing, pause and then start again.

I google a lot but can't find how to do it, probably because i'm not getting the right name for this behaviour.

Add a capture of what I want to accomplish

[text carrousel - vanish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fPwj.png)

[text example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK2Cx.png)

Hope someone can guide me, thanks!

Comment: I would something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/q7hk6nxt/59/.
Apply css animation to move your text within a container of fixed width and overflow: hidden.
You will have to calculate the offset of the scroll each time you apply this animation, but there are many wayss to do this.

Comment: @АрсенийБуров Thanks! I think can work from there. how is this animation named? As you say there are many ways, I want to research more about it.